# Macbook PRO 2015 OS Big SUR Python Crash

Tags: python-3.x, crash, macos-big-sur

I am trying to launch python 3 on my macbook, it use to work before ... now if I launch on the termina "python3" it crash and I got this message.
I don't know what to do...

```
> user:~ my_mac$ python3 dyld: Library not loaded:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
> Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
> Reason: image not found Abort trap: 6
```

I Tried to upgrade the python version and got this message:

```
> ==> python@3.9 Python has been installed as   /usr/local/bin/python3
> 
> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
> `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been
> installed into   /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin
> 
> You can install Python packages with   pip3 install <package> They
> will install into the site-package directory  
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Here the error page.

```
>Process:               Python [65598]
>Path:                  >/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>Identifier:            Python
>Version:               3.5.2 (3.5.2)
>Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
>Parent Process:        bash [48227]
>Responsible:           Terminal [48225]
>User ID:               501
>
>Date/Time:             2021-02-06 09:57:55.710 +0100
>OS Version:            macOS 11.1 (20C69)
>Report Version:        12
>Anonymous UUID:        FB4549E5-EACE-CBB0-1BA6-6767B1DAD93D
>
>Sleep/Wake UUID:       7A0A2DD1-F786-48A4-8641-D98824F7673B
>
>Time Awake Since Boot: 510000 seconds
>Time Since Wake:       5200 seconds
>
>System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
>Crashed Thread:        0
>
>Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
>Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing
>
>Application Specific Information:
>dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
>
>Dyld Error Message:
>  dyld: No shared cache present
>Library not loaded: >/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
>  Referenced from: >/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>  Reason: image not found
>
>Binary Images:
>       0x100000000 -        0x100000fff +org.python.python (3.5.2 - 3.5.2) <78B09BD7-3C8E-0E55->F3A1-BA0FF24E8496> >/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>    0x7fff6679f000 -     0x7fff6683afff  dyld (832.7.1) <DEA51514-B4E8-3368-979B-89D0F8397ABC> >/usr/lib/dyld
>
>Model: MacBookPro11,5, BootROM 425.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 2,8 GHz, 16 >GB, SMC 2.30f2
```